# Que medidas podemos tomar para proteger a emissão de boletos dos malwares que alteram a linha digitável?

Tags: javascript, html, segurança, boleto

Além de emissão em PDF, que pode dificultar alguns clientes pela falta de visualizadores de PDF, que técnicas poderíamos utilizar para proteger ou detectar que o boleto gerado foi modificado pelo malware?

> Vírus que afeta boletos já infecta 192 mil computadores
>
> Um relatório divulgado pela empresa de segurança eletrônica RSA mostra
>   que pelo menos 192 mil computadores foram infectados por um vírus que
>   altera a numeração de boletos bancários. Além disso, segundo a
>   análise, a maioria das máquinas afetadas se encontra no Brasil.
>
> De acordo com a RSA, o vírus é disparado por email e altera a
>   numeração dos boletos bancários no momento do pagamento online,
>   desviando os valores para a conta de uma gangue. A maioria das vítimas
>   é da região Sudeste e já foi identificado que 75% delas utiliza o
>   Windows 7 como sistema operacional. Os usuários do Hotmail são maioria
>   entre os afetados pelo problema.
>
> Segundo informações da revista Info foram gerados 496 mil boletos
>   falsos, muitos deles com valores de até R$ 1,5 mil. O valor total
>   estimado dos documentos fraudulentos pode chegar a R$ 8,5 bilhões. A
>   RSA alerta de demora no processamento do pagamento e lentidão na
>   navegação podem ser indícios que a sua máquina está comprometida.

[Fonte: Tecmundo](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/virus/58644-virus-afeta-boletos-infecta-192-mil-computadores.htm)

Comment: Se entendi direito a noticia, ela fala que o número do boleto é alterado na hora do pagamento, ou seja, na hora que o cara coloca o número no site do banco, então mesmo que fosse um boleto de papel ali que o cara digitou tudo manualmente ainda seria modificado pelo malware

Comment: Na verdade o vírus altera o código html da pagina com o boleto, então mesmo que imprima e pague no caixa, vai imprimir com a linha digitavel e o código de barras dos falsários, e o dinheiro vai pra eles. fonte: http://tecnoblog.net/129088/malware-brasileiro-boletos/

Comment: uma alternativa seria montar a linha digitavel com imagens dos números, o cliente teria que digitar manualmente, mas o vírus não conseguiria modifica-la, pois nem iria detecta-la.

Answer (score 2):

Poderia montar a linha digitável com imagens dos números, ou gerar "on the fly" uma imagem com todo o número, mas isso faria o cliente ter que digitar ela manualmente, sem poder copiar e colar.

Outra opção seria tentar ofuscar ela com elementos HTML ocultos como no exemplo abaixo:

> 041192.11800 26238.100007 19275.041424 2 61480000069739

O codigo HTML ficaria assim:

```
<style>
   .nro { display:none; }
</style>

<span class="nro">Primeira parte da numeração</span><span>041192</span>.<span>11800</span> <span class="nro">Continuação da numeração</span><span>26238</span>.<span>100007</span> <span>19275</span>.<span>041424</span> <span>2</span> <span class="nro">Ultima parte da numeração</span><span>61480000069739</span>
```

creio que assim o malware não conseguiria detecta-la.

---

Ou usando jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var nr1 = '041192';
var nr2 = '11800';
var nr3 = '26238';
var nr4 = '100007';
var nr5 = '19275';
var nr6 = '041424';
var nr7 = '2';
var nr8 = '61480000069739';

$('#ld').html(nr1 + '.' + nr2 + ' ' + nr3 + '.' + nr4 + ' ' + nr5 + '.' + nr6 + ' ' + nr7 + ' ' + nr8 );
});
</script>

<span id="ld"></span>
```

obviamente montar o `<script>` no server side, e para dificultar mais ainda daria pra usar base64_encode nos números, só que teria que implementar uma função no javascript para decodificar, ou até mesmo criar codificação e decodificação do zero.